# XSLT: Copy everything except intermediate elements

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a part of the big xml transformation.

**Input Xml**

```
<Root>
 <Family>
   <Entity>
     <SomeElement1/>
     <ClientVO>
     <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
     <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
     <ClientAddress>
      <AddressLine>Somewhere In downtown</AddressLine>
      <City>Chicago</City>
      <State>IL</State>
     </ClientAddress>
    </ClientVO>
     <Child2>
       <Element2/>
     </Child2>
     <Entity>
     <SomeElement1/>
     <ClientVO>
     <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
     <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
     <ClientAddress>
      <AddressLine>Somewhere In downtown</AddressLine>
      <City>Chicago</City>
      <State>IL</State>
     </ClientAddress>
    </ClientVO>
     <Child2>
       <Element222/>
     </Child2>
   </Entity>
  </Entity>
 </Family>
</Root>
```

**Output Xml**

```
<Response>
 <EntityRoot>
  <SomeElement1/>
 </EntityRoot>

 <ClientInformation>
     <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
     <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
     <AddressLine>Somewhere In downtown</AddressLine>
     <City>Chicago</City>
     <State>IL</State>
    </ClientInformation>

 <Child2Root>
   <Element2>
 </Child2Root>

 <MetadataEntityRoot>
  <SomeElement1/>
 </MetadataEntityRoot>

 <ClientInformation>
     <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
     <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
     <AddressLine>Somewhere In downtown</AddressLine>
     <City>Chicago</City>
     <State>IL</State>
    </ClientInformation>

 <Child2Root>
   <Element222>
 </Child2Root>
</Response>
```

Tried given below xslt but not a feasible solution because there could more elements under `<ClientVO>` or `<ClientAddress>`. It is more of a one to one mapping which I want to avoid.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Entity">
      <EntityRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ClientVO| self::Child2)]" />
      </EntityRoot>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ClientVO| Child2" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ClientVO">
      <ClientInformation>
       <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
       <LastName><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></LastName>
       <xsl:for-each select="ClientAddress">
         <AddressLine><xsl:value-of select="AddressLine"/></AddressLine>
         <City><xsl:value-of select="City"/></City>
         <State><xsl:value-of select="State"/></State>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </ClientInformation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child2">
      <Child2Root><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Child2Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another instance of the same pattern that has been the answer to your last few questions - let the identity template do most of the work for you and just override it where required.  In this case you need to rename `ClientVO` to `ClientInformation`

```
<xsl:template match="ClientVO">
  <ClientInformation>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </ClientInformation>
</xsl:template>
```

and skip through `ClientAddress` but keep processing its children

```
<xsl:template match="ClientAddress">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ian, that's the exact answer I wrote an hour ahead of you. I must admit that this is kind of irritating. :/

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ClientAddress">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to map most things 1:1, start with the identity template and override it as necessary.

Comment: It is part of big translation. Not sure if I have to copy all the nodes again. I will update my question with complete xml and xslt.